# Usuários autenticados

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle11g

como adiciono (usuários autenticados) de volta no NOMES DE GRUPOS OU DE USUÁRIO na aba **segurança** em uma determinada pasta?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei....
Mas vou deixar registrado, caso ajude alguém que tenha a mesma dúvida
Processo.

Windows 7 Professional

1º Botão direito na pasta especificada.

2º Propriedades.

3º Segurança

4º Editar em - Nomes de Grupo ou de usuários.

5º Adicionar

6º Digite o nome **Usuários** e pesquise.

7º O sistema vai retornar a busca do **usuários autenticados**

8º Selecione/ aplique e de OK.

9º As novas configurações serão carregadas.